# Why does my JTable sort integers incorrectly?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

My JTable sorts integers as 1, 10, 100, 101. It looks like its still sorting it as strings. I've looked at similar Questions and tried adjust as necessary. Am I missing something. I've created this using the netbeans GUI creator if that changes anything. I'm also using the method

```
listSubTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

in another section of the code. This sends the result set to the table. Is this taking precedence over the code below. I changed the switch statement to all integers just in case I was getting columns confused. It still list them as Strings.

```
    listSubTable = new javax.swing.JTable(){
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {

        return false;   //Disallow the editing of any cell
    }

};
listSubTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true); 
listSubTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getClickCount() == 1 && isSubdivision()) {
      JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
      int row = target.getSelectedRow();
      int column = target.getSelectedColumn();
     if (listSubTable.getSelectedRow() != -1) {

                row = listSubTable.getSelectedRow();
                archiveNameField.setText("PTC_" + listSubTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, column).toString() + "-V");

            }
    }
if (e.getClickCount() == 1 && !isSubdivision()) {
      JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
      int row = target.getSelectedRow();
      int column = target.getSelectedColumn();
     if (listSubTable.getSelectedRow() != -1) {

                row = listSubTable.getSelectedRow();
                archiveNameField.setText("");
            }
    }
  }
});
listSubTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [] [] {},
    new Integer [] {

    })
    {@Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                return Integer.class;
                case 1:
                return Integer.class;
                case 2:
                return Integer.class;
                default:
                return Integer.class;
            }
        }}

        );

listSubTable.setAutoResizeMode(javax.swing.JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_NEXT_COLUMN);



listSubTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        listSubTableMouseClicked(evt);
    }
});

jScrollPane3.setViewportView(listSubTable);
```

Comment: Add a Sorter with a Comparator for Numeric comparison: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting

Comment: It was there and still did not work. I forgot to set that back where I found it. I was moving that line around to see if it made a difference. I placed it back where it was originally on line 7 above.

Comment: The `getColumnClass` method should actually do the job. I could now remove the unnecessary mess from your posted code and create a [MCVE], but am pretty sure that it would then "work for me". Try to create a [MCVE], and your issue will very likely be resolved quickly.

Comment: I'm always worried of `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)` as you don't know what it's actually doing, or how it's extracting the data from the `ResultSet` - could be using `getString` - it's also creating it's own `TableModel`, so you don't have any control over how it's representing the data - better to make your own functionality to do this

Comment: You do `listSubTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));` then you do `listSubTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(...` you're supplementing one model for another, but not providing any data to the second model - As I said, get rid of `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)` and take control over how the model is created and the data is extracted from the database

Comment: Ok, will implement both Marco13 and MadProgrammer suggestions in the morning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was the line:

```
listSubTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

It must have been getting everything as a String. I replaced it with the following.

```
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (listSubTable.getRowCount() > 0) {
                ((DefaultTableModel) listSubTable.getModel()).removeRow(0);
            }
            int obColumns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            System.out.println("obColumns: " + obColumns);
            while (rs.next()) {
                Object[] obRow = new Object[obColumns];
                obRow[0] = rs.getString(1);
                obRow[1] = rs.getInt(2);
                System.out.println(obRow[0]);
                System.out.println(obRow[1]);

           ((DefaultTableModel)listSubTable.getModel()).insertRow(rs.getRow() - 1, obRow);
            }
```